# How to write to a memory address with an offset in a different process

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I am making a hack for a game called AssaultCube, and the player base address is `0x0050F4F4` and the "health" address is `0x0050F4F4 + 0xF8`, the problem is, I can't write to the address even with Full Access.

My Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    HWND window = FindWindowA(NULL,"AssaultCube");
    int value = 888;
    if(window == NULL) {
        cout << "Can't find window!";
        exit(-1);
    }
    DWORD pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(window,&pid);
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,pid);
    while(true) {
        WriteProcessMemory(handle,reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(0x0050F4F4 + 0xF8),&value,sizeof(value),0);
        Sleep(750);
    }
}
```

Now in the tool I use to look at memory addresses, Cheat Engine, I can change the value but in my program I can't.

[Cheat Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdD2i.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JesperJuhl So what do I do?

Comment: @JesperJuhl First off, how can Cheat Engine modify Physical memory and my program can't? Second off, why so blunt?

Comment: Remember that the address should change each time because of ASLR. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows

Comment: @drescherjm But the address is a static memory address.

Comment: Why don't you check for errors?

Comment: I get no errors when running, and GetLastError doesn't return anything either.

Comment: Your code doesn't call GetLastError. Nor check the return value of WriteProcessMemory.

Comment: @jes: How would a debugger install a software breakpoint in an OS that meets your definition for *"sane"*?

Comment: @Jesper You clearly don't know what WriteProcessMemory does

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The return value of my WriteProcessMemory is 1, so there is no error.

Comment: in this case at `0x0050F4F4 + 0xF8` stored not what you expect. or change only this data not enough. but this already related to concrete program reverse engineering, but not to c++ or winapi

Comment: You need to get the actual base address of the game's process first, then add the offset of the player to that, then add the offset of the health to that. It is very unlikely that the player is located at the same address every time the game is run.

Comment: @pau: This is not a forum. This is a Q&A site. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You state in comments that `WriteProcessMemory` returns 1. In that case, contrary to your beliefs, the value has successfully been written.

Perhaps you are writing to the wrong address, or perhaps the program is overwriting the value. But when the function returns a non-zero it means that it succeeded.

By the way, I strongly recommend that you start including error checking code in the future. Had you done so you would have realised that the function call had succeeded.

Comment: @DavidHefferman Then how come it's not working, in Cheat Engine it shows that the program does not overwrite the value im sending. But magically, Cheat Engine can write to memory but mine can't. There are no errors, I tried GetLastError() and showed nothing, this program is literally perfect but nothing will work. It angers me so much.

Comment: @elitexjj - attach debugger to your Cheat Engine and set bp on `NtWriteVirtualMemory`

Comment: If the function returns a non zero value then it succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incorrect.

0x0050F4F4 is the pointer to the local player object.

0xF8 is health offset, relative to the local player object.

You are adding them together thinking that is the address of the health variable, which it is not.  You need to ReadProcessMemory on 0x0050F4F4, which will yield you the address of the local player object in your destination buffer.  Then you add 0xF8 to it, this yields the address of the local player health variable.  Then you call WriteProcessMemory on this address and overwrite it.